# How to install dig on CentOS?

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, dnf, dig

I can't find the `dig` command on my new CentOS installation. I've tried `dnf install dig` but it say that it cannot find the package.

How do I install dig on CentOS?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The **DIG** tool is part of the [BIND](https://www.isc.org/bind/) Utilities so you need to install them. To install the BIND Utilities, type the following:

```bash
$ dnf install bind-utils
```

Answer (score 66):

You have already provided the specific answer, but if you are looking for other executables or files to see what package they are installed with, utilize `yum whatprovides *relative/path/to/file*`, for example:

```
$ yum whatprovides '*bin/dig'

32:bind-utils-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6.x86_64 : Utilities for querying DNS name servers
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/dig
...
```

From `man yum`:

```
provides or whatprovides
    Is  used to find out which package provides some feature or file. Just
    use a specific name or a file-glob-syntax wildcards to list the  pack-
    ages available or installed that provide that feature or file.
```

Comment: Thanks, putting it all together: `yum install bind-utils`

Answer (score 7):

On legacy systems you'll have to use `yum` instead:

```
$ yum install bind-utils
```

Comment: Confirmed this also works in Amazon Linux 2